# changing in struct proc cause minix freeze

Tags: c++, c, minix

in minix 3.1.2a ,i added an attribute "*hash*" at the end of the **struct proc**

```
struct proc{
.
.
int p_endpoint;     /* endpoint number, generation-aware */

#if DEBUG_SCHED_CHECK
  int p_ready, p_found;
#endif

*int hash;*
}
```

then ,in **main.c** in *main()* i initialized it :

```
for (rp = BEG_PROC_ADDR, i = -NR_TASKS; rp < END_PROC_ADDR; ++rp, ++i) {
    rp->p_rts_flags = SLOT_FREE;        /* initialize free slot */
    rp->p_nr = i;               /* proc number from ptr */

    rp->p_endpoint = _ENDPOINT(0, rp->p_nr); /* generation no. 0 */

        (pproc_addr + NR_TASKS)[i] = rp;        /* proc ptr from number */
        rp->hash=1;
  }
```

and so rebuild with no problem,

now in  **proc.c**,in *pick_proc()* ,if i try to write code that set the "hash" value like:

```
if(hash==1)
hash=0;
```

now,i tried all compiling options

```
make new world
make fresh install
make clean hdboot
make image
```

but the problem still occured when i reboot, it  freeze,as shown :

[image]

but if remove the line

```
hash=0;
```

it works fine

,so please any help i'll be appreciated

Comment: This is very closely related to [In C, can't change a struct attribute except using `#define val`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727152/)  'Closely related' is not, though, 'duplicate' — not necessarily.